# Creating an Extension Method using Expressions

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, extension-methods

I'm trying to write a generic extension method for ordering an IQueryable database collection. (There is more to it, but this is the part I'm s tuck on.)

I want to provide:

> 1. the database class (e.g. Customer,Employer)
> 2. the LINQ expression for the column
> 3. the type of the column (int,string,etc.)

I started with a class that should contain the information but I'm getting stuck how to define and consume the expression.

For the usage I am thinking something like this, but not sure where to provide the type for each column

```
var sortedList = queryable.MyCustomSortMethod<User>( item =>  new List<SortItem> 
    { item.Column_Name, "ASC" },      //string
    { item.Column_BirthYear "DESC" }, //int
    { item.Column_BirthDate, "ASC" }  //date 
}
```

Then I have a class to specify the selector and its direction

```
public class SortItem<TEntity>
{
    public Expression<Func<T> SortFieldSelector<T>  { get; set; }
    public SortDirectionType SortDirectionType { get; set; }  
    //but how to provide column type
}
```

Then the extension method something like this

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity>   MyCustomSortMethod(
    this   IQueryable<TEntity> queryable, 
    List<SortItem<TEntity> selectors)
{

    foreach (var selector in selectors)  {

        if(selector.Direction == "asc")
            queryable = queryable.OrderBy(selector.SortFieldSelector);
        else
            queryable = queryable.OrderByDescending(selector.SortFieldSelector);
    }
    //I need to specify the type of the OrderBy column somehow
    // otherwise compiler errors with "arguments cannot be inferred..." 

    return queryable;

}
```

The rabbit holes I am exploring are getting pretty ugly and I'm sure there is a simple way to do it.

The fact that I need to use an extension method is a firm requirement, but the rest is still flexible if it simplifies the solution.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What's the point? It doesn't seem easier to use than `queryable.OrderBy(item =>  item.Column_Name).ThenByDescending(item => item.Column_BirthYear).ThenBy(item => item.Column_BirthDate)`

Comment: @Thomas - unfortunately I can't do that in this case.  The extension method has some additional logic if the list is empty(and based on some additional parameters).  I'm trying to keep that logic contained in the extension method to avoid code duplication in the calling code.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
public class SortItem<TEntity>
{
    public Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> Selector { get; }
    public ListSortDirection Direction { get; }

    public SortItem(Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector, ListSortDirection direction)
    {
        Selector = selector;
        Direction = direction;
    }    
}


public static IQueryable<TEntity> MyCustomSortMethod<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> queryable,
    IEnumerable<SortItem<TEntity>> selectors)
{
    foreach (var selector in selectors)
    {
        IOrderedQueryable<TEntity> ordered = queryable as IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>;
        if (ordered == null)
        {
            if (selector.Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                queryable = queryable.OrderBy(selector.Selector);
            else
                queryable = queryable.OrderByDescending(selector.Selector);
        }
        else
        {
            if (selector.Direction == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                queryable = ordered.ThenBy(selector.Selector);
            else
                queryable = ordered.ThenByDescending(selector.Selector);
        }
    }
    return queryable;
}
```

(note the use of `ThenBy` instead of `OrderedBy`; if you use `OrderBy` every time, it just overrides the previous order, instead of completing it)

Disclaimer: I didn't try it, so I'm not sure it actually works with `Func<TEntity, object>`.